# Reading and storing whole words from file to array

Tags: c, file, text

I would like to analyze words inside a text file (length of each word, starting character, etc). To do so, the first step is to read each word from the file, and proceed to store in an array.

In the following code I managed to store all the characters inside an array, but did not separate into words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


FILE *inp;
char arr[100];
int i = 0;
int word_count = 0;
char c;
int char_count = 0;

inp = fopen("string_in.txt", "r");

    while ((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
        printf("\n");
        arr[char_count] = c;
        word_count++;
    }
    else {
        //printf("%c", c); //print to check if file is being read correctly
        arr[char_count] = c; 
        printf("%c",arr[char_count]);
    }   
    char_count++;
}
printf("\n");
printf("Chars: %d, Words: %d\n", char_count, word_count+1);

printf("From array: \n");
for(i = 0; i <= word_count; i++) {
    printf("%c",arr[word_count]);
}

printf("\n");
fclose(inp);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Input text:

```
This is a test
```

Output:

```
This
is
a
test
Chars: 15, Words: 4
From array:
This is a test
```

I would like to access elements as follows:

```
arr[0] = 'This'
arr[3] = 'Test'
```

but since I am string by character and not by word:

```
arr[0] = 'T'
arr[3] = 's'
```

Any suggestions on how this can be extended to store full words?

---

**EDIT:**

As per the answer below:

```
while ((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF) {
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
    printf("\n");

    arr[word_count][char_count] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
    char_count = 0; //Reset the counter.
    word_count++;
}
else {
     arr[word_count][char_count] = c; 
     printf("%c",arr[word_count][char_count]);
}   
(char_count < 99)? (char_count++):(char_count = 0);
}


printf("From array: \n");
for(i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
    printf("%s",arr[word_count]);
}
```

Prints no output from array.

```
This
is
a
test
Chars: 5, Words: 4
From array:

 Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

Comment: You are not storing the full word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have space to store single `string`.

```
char arr[100]; -->char arr[100][100];
```

Then your reading changes as  below.

```
while ((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
        printf("\n");

        arr[word_count][char_count] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
        char_count = 0; //Reset the counter.
        word_count++;
    }
    else {
         arr[word_count][char_count] = c; 
         printf("%c",arr[word_count][char_count]);

         if (char_count < 99)
              char_count++;
            else
              char_count = 0;
    }   
}
```

And your printing changes as below.

```
for(i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
    printf("%s",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Will test this out. Should the ternary operator end in  `char_count == 0`, instead of `=0` ?

Comment: @Rrz0 No I'm resetting `char_count` to 0 if it reaches 100 chars. It is just to avoid access out of bound. In reality that condition should not meet. You should reserve more memory if needed.

Comment: For some reason I am yet to figure out I keep getting `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` on that line.

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately I get no output printed. Will update question

Comment: Please change that horrible conditional expression into a normal `if` statement.

Comment: @Rrz0 Updated please check now.

Comment: This is similar to the answer posted by Alex, where we are printing `arr[i]`, only `This` is printed

Comment: @Rrz0 I verified it is working on my environment with the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works with the if-else statement! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As other users said, you have to use 2D arrays. They are declared and initialized this way: `arr[10][100]` (10 will be the number of words to store, change this according to your needs).

```
while ((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {
        printf("\n");
        arr[word_count][char_count]='\0';
        char_count=0;
        word_count++;
    }
    else {
        arr[word_count][char_count] = c;
        printf("%c",arr[word_count][char_count]);
        char_count++;
    }
    if(char_count>=100) // security in case a word is too long
        char_count=0;
}
word_count++;

printf("\n");
printf("Chars: %d, Words: %d\n", char_count, word_count);

printf("From array: \n");
for(i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
    printf("%s ",arr[i]);
}
```

Keep in mind that because I reset `char_count` every time there is a new word, its value after the loop won't be what you expect (it will be the length of the last word only) and the value displayed in the printf will be wrong. If you actually care about it you will have to create another variable.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, this only prints :`This` from the array

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Char ** to store the words fully

> array[100][100]

Because in array[100] you store a single string therefore when accessing array[0] you only access the first letter of that string.

You would need to chnage your code and implementing a double array instead of a single one